# How to get only certain fields from a given file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I have list of employees in following format

```
Name: 
Phone No:
Email: 

Name:
Address:
Phone No:
Email:

Name:
Country:
Address:
Phone No:
Email:

Name:
Address:

Name :
Email:
Address:
```

All I want is that to get only Name and Email address.

I tried something like `cat filename | grep -e ^Name: -e ^Email:` but was not 100% successfull.

Comment: this should work 100%, can you provide us with error ? either lines missed to wrong lines found.(appart that you shoud not `cat | grep` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `|` which is "or" operator for regex in the grep command. Also, no need for `cat`. `grep` can read from file directly.

```
grep '^Name:\|^Email:' filename
```

Comment: or `grep -E '^(Name|Email):' filename`.  `^` and `:` are common to both sub-expressions, leaving only `Name` and `Email` as the non-fixed portion of the extended regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If by "not 100% successful" you mean that you want only the values of the fields, without the field-names, then you need to use `awk` rather than grep.

e.g.

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /^(Name|Email)$/ {print $2}' filename
```

Or, if you still want each record separated by a blank line:

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /^(Name|Email)$/ {print $2}; /^[[:space:]]*$/ {print "\n"}' filename
```